# |{all real functions with unequal behaviours at infinity}|

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f,g$ be arbitrary elements of the set $F$ of all functions $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, and define an equivalence relation $$\Omega(f(x))=\Omega(g(x))~\Leftrightarrow~\exists~\varepsilon:f(\delta)=g(\delta)~\;\forall~\;\delta>\varepsilon.$$
What is the cardinality of the set $S$ of all such equivalence classes of $F$?

We know by Cantor's Theorem that $|F|=|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}|=2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$, and since $\mathbb{R}$ is also a subset of $S$ (where $f$ are constant), we have $|\mathbb{R}|\leq|S|\leq2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$. I.e. $|S|=|\mathbb{R}|$ or $2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$, but which?

Comment: Your title states functions that have unequal behavior at infinity, but the body of the post is regarding equivalence classes of functions that are constant in neighborhoods of infinity. Which do you mean?

Comment: Equivalence classes of functions that are equal for all large enough arguments in $\mathbb{R}$.  I wasn't sure how to best squeeze that into the title; does it need to be changed?

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense for the title to say equal behavior in the title?

Comment: The question is only interested in functions that are distinct in that regard

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the cardinality of $S$ is the same as that of $F$.

To show this pick a bijection $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,1)$, which shows that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^{(0,1)}$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Can you see a way of injecting $\mathbb{R}^{(0,1)}$ into $S$? That is, a way of injecting $\mathbb{R}^{(0,1)}$ into $F$ so that unequal functions $(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ must be sent to functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that aren't equivalent under your relation?

Comment: $f(1)>g(1)$ (or rather their limits if the interval must be open) iff $f(x)>g(x)$ under my relation? If so perfect answer, thank you

Comment: If think you've misunderstood something about your equivalence relation: it doesn't naturally give rise to an ordering. In particular, it is entirely possible for to non-equivalent functions to alternate which is greater infinitely many times as they head of to infinity. Have a think about it a bit more.

Comment: Forgive me, this came up in some analysis-style work and I have very little background in set theory. I'm interested in sets of functions that *are* totally ordered, hence the definition (replacing $=$ with $\geq$, for instance). Could you point me to a resource if the theory required is as basic as it seems?